# Time complexity of os.walk in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I've to calculate the time-complexity of an algorithm, but in it I'm calling os.walk which I can't consider as a single operation but many.

The sources of os.walk left me confused as the filetree may be ordered in many ways (1.000.000 files in a folder or a file per folder and 1.000.000 folders.

I'm not an expert on time-complexities, I can't be sure on what I should consider as only an operation or many, so this left me stuck. Don't count the simlink flag, which I assume set to false to ignore them.

PD: I found the sources of os.walk in the Komodo IDE, but I wouldn't know how to find them as the javadocs.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "javadocs" for Python. But you can find all the source code online in the main repo. For example, `os.walk` for 3.3 is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/os.py#l337).

Comment: You don't necessarily need to know how many operations each function takes, as long as it's invariant to the variable you're investigating. If N isn't at all related to the number of files in your directory, then you can consider `walk` to be constant time.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the sources. I was looking for something like this for a while without luck. I found it in the IDE but that's a cheap trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... let's walk through the source :)

Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

```
def walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False):
    islink, join, isdir = path.islink, path.join, path.isdir

    try:
        # Note that listdir and error are globals in this module due
        # to earlier import-*.


        # Should be O(1) since it's probably just reading your filesystem journal
        names = listdir(top)
    except error, err:
        if onerror is not None:
            onerror(err)
        return

    dirs, nondirs = [], []


    # O(n) where n = number of files in the directory
    for name in names:
        if isdir(join(top, name)):
            dirs.append(name)
        else:
            nondirs.append(name)

    if topdown:
        yield top, dirs, nondirs

    # Again O(n), where n = number of directories in the directory
    for name in dirs:
        new_path = join(top, name)
        if followlinks or not islink(new_path):

            # Generator so besides the recursive `walk()` call, no additional cost here.
            for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
                yield x
    if not topdown:
        yield top, dirs, nondirs
```

Since it's a generator it all depends on how far you walk the tree, but it looks like `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of files/directories in the given path.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Wolph. I was wondering if recursive call to walk() at the last lines won't add a complexity O(N*m) where N is the total amount of files and m is the minimum amount of subfolders under root. After all, you're recursing over a tree branch by branch.

Comment: In my `n` I include both files and directories. The recursion just makes the `n` bigger since it will process more files/directories, but it will still go through every file/directory only once. So in the end your `n` will the the total count of all files and directories in the path.

Answer (score 5):

This is too long for a comment:  in CPython, a `yield` passes its result to *the immediate caller*, **not** directly to the ultimate consumer of the result.  So, if you have recursion going `R` levels deep, a chain of `yield`s at each level delivering a result back up the call stack to the ultimate consumer takes `O(R)` time.  It also takes `O(R)` time to resume the `R` levels of recursive call to get back to the lowest level where the first `yield` occurred.

So each result `yield`'ed by `walk()` takes time proportional to the level in the directory tree at which the result is first `yield`'ed.

That's the theoretical ;-) truth.  In practice, however, this makes approximately no difference unless the recursion is very deep.  That's because the chain of `yield`s, and the chain of generator resumptions, occurs "at C speed".  In other words, it *does* take `O(R)` time, but the constant factor is so small most programs never notice this.

This is especially true of recursive generators like `walk()`, which almost never recurse deeply.  Who has a directory tree nested 100 levels?  Nope, me neither ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` (unless you prune it, or have symlink issues) guarantees to list each directory in the subtree exactly once.

So, if you assume that listing a directory is linear on the number of entries in the directory,* then if there are N total directory entries in your subtree, `os.walk` will take O(N) time.

Or, if you want the time for `walk` to produce each value (the root, dirnames, filenames tuple): if those N directory entries are split among M subdirectories, then each of the M iterations takes amortized O(N/M) time.

---

* Really, that's up to your OS, C library, and filesystem not Python, and it can be much worse than O(N) for older filesystems… but let's ignore that.